# Why I am I unable to instantiate eventEmitter obj using the code below

Tags: node.js

I have an error instantiating eventEmitter object with the below syntax:

```
const events=new require('events').EventEmmiter();// throws error
```

But the next method works:

```
const events=require('events');
const myEvent=new events.EventEmmiter();// no error
```

I expect that an object is created but I am facing the below error

> TypeError: (intermediate value).EventEmmiter is not a function

What's going on, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try Emitter not Emmiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` has the same precedence as member access `.`, and gets evaluated left-to-right, so:

```
const events = new require('events').EventEmitter(); // throws error
```

is like

```
const events = (new require('events')).EventEmitter(); // throws error
```

Similarly, you can make an instantiation of DOMParser and *immediately* call a method of the instance (parseFromString) without any grouping parentheses:

```js
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<div>foo<div>', 'text/html');
// equivalent to
//const doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString('<div>foo<div>', 'text/html');
```

This is wrong because you want to call `require` as a normal function, not with `new` - you want `new` to go with the `EventEmitter` call instead.

You can fix it by putting parentheses from the `require` to `EventEmitter`, so that you can call the `EventEmitter` constructor with `new`:

```
const events = new (require('events').EventEmitter)();
```

(make sure to get the spelling right too)